git submodule doesn't work returning .git Not a directory. Unable to determinate absolute path of git directory
I have a repository, in which I want to create a subrep with the submodule command.
When I run
git submodule add https://<login>:<pass>@bitbucket.[hidden]/documents.git

the command returns:
.../.git: Not a directory
Unable to determine absolute path of git directory

I am working with Bitbucket, but I am sure it shouldn't be the problem.
What can be the cause of the problem? If I clone it aside, it does that without any issues. Maybe there is another way I can create a clone repository inside another one?

Solved it. The problem was that the original git folder was on the corporate network drive. For some reason, git submodule doesn't want to work with it.
Placed both gits on C: drive and everything works fine.
